Vue3 Swiper/Vue-Awesome-Swiper not working
I'm trying to use some swiper in my project (any of them, since it works, no preferences) and I just can't get it working. All versions I tried (5, 7, 8, 9, 11, Swiper Element) throw errors back to me concerning the import statements on my main.js, like:
'This dependency was not found:

swiper/vue in ./node_modules/vue-awesome-swiper/index.js

To install it, you can run: npm install --save swiper/vue
 [webpack.Progress] 100%'
Im using yarn as my pack manager, it could be a problem?
It seems none of this versions is working, someone could give me some help on troubleshooting this? Maybe I'm missing something.
Thanks in advance!!

run npm i swiper to install swiper  package https://www.npmjs.com/package/swiper

I did it already @BorisMaslennikov, the problem is the import statements, I just copy them from the docs and it dosen't work, it seems the docs are out of date.

The vue-awesome-swiper project has been deprecated and superseded by Swiper Vue component, a TypeScript friendly project which is a recent official release provided by Swiper. For better stability, please migrate as soon as possible. - remove it from you project and use just swiper

So @BorisMaslennikov, I tried it already and the same problems: I install via npm following the docs instructions and I get errors on import statemens. Did u use it already? Does it work?

I added the answer. please try

According to this page :

Swiper Vue components will likely to be removed in future versions. It is recommended to migrate to Swiper Element instead.

I tried Swiper Element example and it worked:
do not forget to npm uninstall vue-awesome-swiper first
npm install swiper

main.js(ts)
import { register } from 'swiper/element/bundle';
register();

App.vue
<swiper-container>
  <swiper-slide>Slide 1</swiper-slide>
  <swiper-slide>Slide 2</swiper-slide>
  <swiper-slide>Slide 3</swiper-slide>
</swiper-container>

here is my build log:
vite v5.2.9 building for production...
✓ 46 modules transformed.
dist/index.html                  0.36 kB │ gzip:  0.26 kB
dist/assets/index-DWYNT8DU.js  232.99 kB │ gzip: 71.69 kB
✓ built in 993ms

StackBlitz.com

Thank a lot, but it didn´t work for me. Think I have some issue concerning pack managers. Using yarn to manage my project. I just can serve my project using node15, but to install swiper it asks me to switch to node17. I do that and switch back to node15 to serve my project. Put the import statements and got this error:
This dependency was not found:

swiper/element/bundle in ./src/main.js

To install it, you can run: npm install --save swiper/element/bundle
 [webpack.Progress] 100%
Error from chokidar (C:): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\DumpStack.log.tmp'

node15 is quite old... I would better find the way to switdh to latest version.

I'll leave working example here. just in case. https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-swiper-stackoverflow?file=src%2FApp.vue

I tried install using node18.4.0/18.12.0 and got this error:
$ npm install swiper
npm ERR! Unexpected token '.'
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!   C:\Users\julia\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2024-04-28T18_56_18_168Z-debug-0.log.
Any idea?
